# Given a full name (First Last) as one scalar entered by the user, how can I print the first and last names individually?

Tags: string, perl, scalar

I'm pretty new at Perl.  I have to have the user enter their full name and then print just the first, just the last, and the in "last, first" format.

I basically just have

```
chomp ($name = <\STDIN>);
```

so far.  And a bunch of stuff that hasn't worked. Ignore the '\' in the STDIN, this is my first post and I couldn't figure out formatting.

Solved:

```
chomp ($name = <STDIN>);
$first = substr $name, 0, rindex($name, ' ');
$last = substr $name, (rindex($name, ' ')+1);
print "\nFirst Name: ".$first;
print "\nLast Name: ".$last;
print "\nLast, first: ".$last.", ".$first;
```

Got it figured out with some better google searches.

Comment: You need to think about what should happen when the user does not have one first and one last name. Examples to consider: `Johann Sebastian Bach` (2 first names), `Claus von Stauffenberg` (1 first name, last name is “von Stauffenberg”). Some names have numerals in them. In some cultures, the surname precedes the given name, e.g. `Li Xi`. Some cultures do not have surnames at all. What cases do you want to cover?

Comment: The combination of `rindex()` and `substr()` is probably the most complex approach you could have chosen. Far better to go with `split()`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the name contains exactly one surname which cointains no spaces, and an arbitrary number of first names, we can do this:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

chomp(my $full_name = <>);          # read a name
my @names = split ' ', $full_name;  # split it at spaces
my $last_name = pop @names;         # remove last name from the @names
my $first_name = join ' ', @names;  # reassemble the remaining names

say "First name: $first_name";      # say is print that always appends a newline
say "Last name: $last_name";
say "Last, first: $last_name, $first_name";
```

Always `use strict; use warnings;` to get as much error reports as possible. If you ignore them you likely have a bug. It also forces you to declare all variables.

Functions like `rindex` and `index` are rarely used in Perl. Regexes are often a more expressive alternative. We could also have done:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

chomp(my $full_name = <>);
my ($first_name, $last_name) = $full_name =~ /^(.*)\s+(\S+)$/;

say "First name: $first_name";
say "Last name: $last_name";
say "Last, first: $last_name, $first_name";
```

That regex means: `^` anchor at the start of the string, `(.*)` consume and remember as many characters as possible, `\s+` match one or more whitespace characters, `(\S+)` consume and remember one or more non-whitespace characters, `$` anchor at line end.

Answer (score 0):

Please read perl [split](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html) function .

```
my $data = <STDIN> 
my @values = split(' ', $data);
my $first = $values[0];
my $last = $values[1];
```

I hope this could help